# Sorting Dependent Dropdown Lists in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to be able to sort the 'Country' and 'City' columns on the Countries page in the below Google Sheet but when I do so (sort option in A4 and B4) the data gets corrupted and the dependent dropdown lists don't work anymore.

Is this possible and how could I do it?

If possible, I would also like to be able to sort the information in the Country Dropdowns page (B3:E3) in a way that the above stated would still work.

Used in Aux Country Dropdown page:

`=IFNA(TRANSPOSE(INDEX('Country Dropdowns'!$B$4:$E$15,, MATCH(Countries!A5,'Country Dropdowns'!$B$3:$E$3,0))))`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wPbWdUx1cAWVhMdrxm_x5Vdy_ExYsV6Srn_Lu3FXHJg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Will be an answer based on [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) valid for you?

Comment: Hi Emel, yes that is fine as well. I am just not that familiar with it and thus thought that this way would better suit me. Do you have a script in mind? Thank you!

Comment: @kcin I have a solution for you. Please make your sheet editable so I can show you

Answer (score 2):

First of all for your `Country Dropdowns` sheet create some helper columns and do your sorting there. So for `USA` in cell `G3` use this formula and pull to the left for other countries

```
=INDEX({B3;SORT(B4:B)})
```

Next. In your `B5` cell in the `Aux Country Dropdown` sheet use this single formula:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(HLOOKUP('mar Countries'!$A5:A,'mar Country Dropdowns'!$G$3:$J$15,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},0)))
```

Finally fix your drop-downs in your `Countries` sheet by using in `A5` this formula and drag down

```
='Country Dropdowns'!$G$3:$J$3
```

also for your `B5` cell drop-down use the following formula and drag down

```
='Aux Country Dropdown'!$C5:$I5
```

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, thank you for your answer! I tried sorting 'mar Countries' but choices in the 'City' column give similar errors. Most important would be to be able to sort on this page. Do you know why the errors are received?

Comment: @kcin *"I tried sorting 'mar Countries' but choices in the 'City' column give similar errors"*. You should not sort anything. Cities get "auto-sorted" in columns `G-J`

Comment: @marikamirsos I'm sorry, I think I was unclear in my description. I'd like to be able to use the filter dropdown menu (see A4:B4 in 'mar Countries') to sort the dependent dropdown lists. This also when there are more columns with info in 'mar Countries' in addition to A4:B4. When using the sort in the dropdown menu, I run into problems and the data is not displayed correctly.

Comment: @kcin *" I'd like to be able to use the filter dropdown menu (see A4:B4 in 'mar Countries') to sort the dependent dropdown lists."*  **Sort them as much as you like. Still. For the formula use the helper columns `G-J`**. That is why they are called helper columns. You can also add as many columns as you want in `Countries`. Just remember to add a helper column for each new column.  You say you run into problems. I cannot see why. Have you followed the formulae to a T?

Comment: I'm using the worksheet 'mar Countries' you made and inserted the filter  button for both columns there to do the sorting. This gives me errors (see file). I didn't do my own one.

Comment: Sorry but you're asking cannot be done. Not unless you use helper columns as shown.

Comment: Okay, thank you for trying to help out!

Comment: Still. I don't see why you insist on not using helper columns which would get your desired results. Anyway.

Comment: I'll look into the helper columns. I'm just not knowledgeable in the area so that's why I was hoping the other option would suffice. Thank you!